# Fetch a specific row in mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to fetch a specific row from a table in my DB, i.e. only what's pertinent to the user that's logged in. I'm using the following script for this:

```
<?php
 include('./classes/DB.php');
 include('./classes/Login.php');

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gaming");  
$playerid = Login::isLoggedIn();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM games";// WHERE player_id =" .$playerid;  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
$json_array = array();  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {  
        if ($row['player_id']==$playerid) {
            $json_array[] = $row;  
        }
   }  

echo json_encode($json_array); 
?>
```

Login.php:

```
<?php 

class Login {

public static function isLoggedIn() {

    if (isset($_COOKIE['CHEZA'])) {
        if (DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token',    array(':token'=>sha1($_COOKIE['CHEZA'])))) {
            $userid = DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($_COOKIE['CHEZA'])))[0]['user_id'];
            if (isset($_COOKIE['CHEZACHEZA'])) {
                    return $userid;
            } else {
                $cstrong = True;
                $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
                DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES (\'\', :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':user_id'=>$userid));
                DB::query('DELETE FROM login_tokens WHERE token=:token', array(':token'=>sha1($_COOKIE['CHEZA'])));
                setcookie("CHEZA", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
                setcookie("CHEZACHEZA", '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
                return $userid;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
?>
```

I get the desired response in my browser but when I use a REST client all I get is an empty array [ ]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your rest client is not logged in i guess. If it needs a session then you need to authenticate and set a session cookie.

Comment: You could try to var_dump($result) and see what turns up in the REST client.

Comment: Why are you using the conditional in the `while` instead of using the `where` clause? (You should parameterize, but this implementation is not optimal)

Comment: give isloggedin() code

Comment: when I echo $playerid it gives the correct id of the user that is logged in so I don't think that's where the problem is

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar I've added the code

Comment: Your code is poorly written performance-wise. `Login::isLoggedIn()` will run the it's queries over and over when calling it, instead of putting the value once in a variable. Also, why are you executing the exact same query twice, one time inside the `if`, and right after for getting user id?

Comment: Hey there. It's really hard to give an answer that is more than speculation as the code shown here should generally work despite the problems mentioned already. In any event, please note that the original query is using concatenation **which is prone to SQL injection**. Please read on that and possibly rewrite this code, it might be easier to start over from scratch.

Comment: I cannot se any query concatenation.

Comment: @Tobia the commented part of the first select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$playerid = Login::isLoggedIn();
```

is not set, check it.

**EDIT**

Now the code of `isLoggedIn()` is published: are you sure your REST client is sending the CHEZA cookie? I don't think it is a good idea to use cookies in REST call. I found useful this reading: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141019/should-cookies-be-used-in-a-restful-api

Comment: I'm able to get this response when I use the browser: `[{"id":"3","player_id":"15","level":"6","score":"10000"}] ` and it's the user with id of 15 that's logged in

Comment: Ok but maybe there is a cookie in your browser. Can you log the value during the rest request?

Comment: there's definitely a cookie in the browser, that's where the problem lies! I need to rewrite isLoggedIn()

Comment: hmm, no, please don't beg for question acceptance, and please clarify your answer. "setted" is not a word as far as I know, and you mention nothing of cookies.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier first of all i cannot see my comment anymore and I did not delete it, I do not think it was offensive. Sorry for the non-english word of my answer, english is not my mothertoungue and this should not be a blame, I will edit it. When I read this question I speculated where there were the error and I did guess right, if you read the second post of this answer I wrote about cookies: I supposed why Macharia could get good result from browser but not from a REST call. Now the question is changed because 13h ago there were not isLoggedIn() code published.

Comment: Hey there. There's no problem with not being fluent in English, I pointed it out, you corrected it, all for the best. However now it becomes apparent that you have no answer, you are taking guesses and asking for clarifications, **which is not what an answer is for**. You have more than enough reputation to comment on the question until you know enough to give a real answer.

Comment: The question was _What am I doing wrong?_ and my answer was _$playerid is not set_. At that time `isLoggedIn()` content was unknow. I will wait for your answer to understand how a good answer can be.

Comment: As @Tobia has pointed out, the REST client is not sending the cookie which is what's resulting in a blank response. Thanks also for the additional reading!

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your php code to this, I have added an **isset** check before running your query and logic code :

```
<?php
 include('./classes/DB.php');
 include('./classes/Login.php');

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gaming");  
$playerid = Login::isLoggedIn();

if(isset($playerid)){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE player_id =" .$playerid;  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
$json_array = array();  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {  
        if ($row['player_id']==$playerid) {
            $json_array[] = $row;  
        }
   }  

echo json_encode($json_array); 
}

?>
```

if it doesn't works, try adding a `print_r($playerid)` and check if you are getting the **loggedin** user id.

Comment: That would still not work if the method returns false, you need to make sure that it's not false, and possibly numeric

Comment: It has to do with cookies as Tobia has pointed out, there's no cookie set in the REST client hence the blank response.